# Wrong syntax highlight for shell script in vim

Tags: shell, vim, syntax, youcompleteme

I'm new to vim and shell script. I'm not sure if there is a real problem or it is just me not understanding vim or shell script, but I did search through the google and got no answer. Anyway, this is what I got when I doing shell script in vim. And I think the syntax highlight is not working correctly.

[image: See image click here]

```
filename=$(basename $file)
```

Vim highlights the `$(` and `)` in red colour.

BTW: I'm using gvim 8.0 on Mac and had YCM installed, if it is relevant.

Comment: Sorry, but why exactly you say it is not working? Seems to be working in the image

Comment: Hi @sidyll So I'm thinking that I do not having any syntax error in my code But vim did highlight some of my code in red (as shown in the image). Did you mean that I do having a syntax error? My script works fine on my labtop.

Comment: To me that's just the way your colorscheme does it :) have you tried another one?

Comment: I just checked syntax definition for shell, and in fact the sub commands have the highlight definition inside the Error group. They will thus be displayed formatted that way by default, unless you change your syntax or use a coloscheme less invasive in that particular highlight group. But nothing wrong with your syntax anyway, it's just the default.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has to do with the behavior of Vim's shell syntax. It has three modes: posix shell, ksh, and bash. You are using bash syntax, but Vim is rendering it as posix shell (the default).

Here is a screenshot of 3 different versions of this code in Vim 8.0.

[image]

The top version is just the code you posted in your screenshot. By default, it is using posix shell mode, and you can see that the red highlights are present.

In the middle version, I have added `#!/bin/sh` to the beginning of the file. This is still in posix mode, and still has the red highlights.

At the bottom, you can see I switched to `#!/bin/bash`. This triggers the bash behavior, and now you can see the bash-specific syntax is no longer marked as an error.

The `#!` line is used to auto-detect the file type. However, if it is missing, it is still possible to force the mode, if you wish to.

```
:let b:is_bash=1
:set ft=sh
```

Note that the mode is set when the file is opened. So adding `#!/bin/bash` won't immediately fix the mode. You would need to save/exit the file, and then open it again, to switch to bash mode. (Or use the trick just above this paragraph.)